# How to compare a text with accents in cypress?

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress

I try to compare a text in cypress, my text has words with accents and it throws the following error ...

**AssertionError Timed out retrying: expected** '' to have text '\n Su lote de distribuci�n se ha creado correctamente, en breve sus comprobantes se enviar�n a sus respectivos destinatarios.\n', **but the text was** '\n Su lote de distribución se ha creado correctamente, en breve sus comprobantes se enviarán a sus respectivos destinatarios.\n

Comment: most probably you found a new [issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/new/choose) in cypress

Answer (score 1):

I could make it work by replacing the accented words with their corresponding unicode symbol, which for ñ was \u00F3n